# Remove every character from a string except the numbers and characters between them

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

The problem I'm facing is that I'm unable to get number from a string along with dot or comma between those numbers.

Example string: 'kr.2.000,00 DKK' OR '$150.65 USD' OR '€340.00 EUR'

From this string I need to fetch '2.000,00' using regex. so basically the regex would be to fetch numbers and any character that is between them and store them in a variable.

This is my code:

```
var oldPrice = 'kr.2.000,00 DKK';
var newPrice = oldPrice.replace(/^\d+(\.|,)?\d+(\.|,)?\d+$/igm, "");
```

I need 2.00,00 in variable newPrice. Please help guys!

Comment: You are anchoring your regex with `^` and `$` and therefor you don't get a match. Remove the anchors.

Comment: I tried removing it, doesn't solves. :|

Comment: Is the format of `oldPrice` fixed? If yes, you can simply use `/\d.+\d/`.

Comment: No, It might vary that's the basic example. It can be '$150.65 USD' OR '€340.00 EUR' OR price with any other currency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```js
var oldPrice = 'kr.2.000,00 DKK';
var newPrice = oldPrice.match(/\d+.*\d+/)[0];
```

The ".*" represents the part you said "..and any character that is between them"

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern is on the right track, and you only need to remove the `^` and `$` anchors to make it work.  Then, apply it repeatedly over your input string to extract the values you want.  Note that one change I did make to the pattern was to allow the separator/digits portion after the initial numbers to repeat any number of times.  This covers an input such as `1,500,000`, which has more than one thousands separator.

```js
var re = /\d+(?:[,.]?\d+)*[,.]?\d+/g;
var input = "kr.2.000,00 DKK' OR '$150.65 USD' OR '€340.00 EUR OR ¥1,500,000";
var m;

do {
    m = re.exec(input);
    if (m) {
        console.log(m[0]);
    }
} while (m);
```